# I need a function that I can apply to a string to return the string value or "00" if it is null

Tags: c#

Is there some function that I can apply to a string so that the string will return its value if the string is not equal to null or the value "00" if it is null.

```
var abc = myVariable.xxxx;

gives abc = "AB" if myVariable == "AB";
gives abc = "00" if myVariable == null;
```

Comment: have you even tried to solve it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
var abc = myVariable ?? "00";
```

This uses the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Comment: Might be worth wrapping the code in a String extension method too.

Comment: @KevRitchie: I wondered about that, but is it really worth it? Would you wrap other operators in extension methods? If it's being used *with the same default value* from several places, then maybe... but I wouldn't write a method just to change this to `myVariable.DefaultIfNull("00")`.

Comment: Very true, totally agree if it's only in one place then it's a bit overkill.  I just wanted to give a different approach incorporating the syntax the OP wanted above.

Answer (score 4):

```
string abc = myVariable ?? "00";
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a String [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to encapsulate the answer that @JonSkeet gave.

Create a new class in your project called ExtensionMethods or whatever you would prefer and put the extension method in that class e.g.

```
static class Extensions
{
        public static String ConvertNullValue(this String value)
        {
            return value ?? "00";
        }
}
```

You could then use this extension method against your string variable `myVariable` like this:

```
var abc = myVariable.ConvertNullValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string abc = myVariable.xxxx ?? "00"
```